# Compiling a directive inside another directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that can output plain HTML or another directive. I'm having trouble getting the inner directive to compile, right now Angular is just sticking the actual directive tag into my html without compiling it.

Here's a screenshot of the Chrome Inspector showing the un-compiled directive
[image: The Chrome Inspector showing the un-compiled directive]

Basically, I am using `$sce.trustAsHtml("<html-string-here>")` which will allow HTML, but it will not compile the directive.

If I wrap that in `$compile($sce.trustAsHtml("<html-string-here>"))($scope)` then it throws errors. **What am I missing here?**

---

**Full Demo Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/nozauLzo/3/**

**Simplified demo explained below**

---

I have this list

```
$scope.list = [{
    id:1,
    content: "some plain text"
},{
    id:2,
    content: "<strong>some HTML!</strong>"
},{
    id:3,
    content: "<inner-directive text='A Directive!'></inner-directive>"
}];
```

I bind to that list like this:

```
<outer-directive ng-repeat="item in list" data="item"></outer-directive>
```

And that directive is built like this

```
myTestApp.directive("outerDirective",["$sce", "$compile", function($sce, $compile){

    function getLink($scope){
        var trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.data.content);
        $scope.trustedContent = trustedHtml;
        //This will break it!
        //var compiledHtml = $compile(trustedHtml)($scope);
        //$scope.trustedContent = compiledHtml ;
        //console.log(trustedHtml, compiledHtml)
    }

     function getTemplate(){
         return ""+
             "<div class='outer'>"+
             "  #{{data.id}} -- "+
             "  <span ng-bind-html='trustedContent'></span>"+
             "</div>";
    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            data: "="
        },
        link: getLink,
        template: getTemplate
    };
}]);
```

Comment: you aren't going to be able to do what you are trying to do... there are multiple questions on the site of people trying (and failing) to do similar things.  By the time the data is evaluated, the compile has already been processed.  Modifying the order would only lead to infinite digest cycles.

Comment: :( really? Well dang. I'll have to go about this in another way then.  Thanks for the tip, now I can stop beating my head against the desk.